# undefined symbol: _ZN5boost21recursive_timed_mutexC1Ev when importing .so file in python

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-thread

I have problem including a shared object file in my python script, running ubuntu 16.04. The files to this script are supplied to me and I have no possibility to recompile them. It is a file using old boost libraries (1.34.1) thread and serialization. The error I get is:
`ImportError: ./libsubs_reg.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5boost21recursive_timed_mutexC1Ev`

Checking dependent libraries for libsus_reg:

```
# readelf -d libsubs_reg.so
Dynamic section at offset 0x27118 contains 28 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libboost_serialization-gcc42-mt-1_34_1.so.1.34.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libboost_thread-gcc42-mt-1_34_1.so.1.34.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

I have created links from the 1.34.1 boost versions to the currently installed, 1.58.0.

```
# ldd libsub_reg.so
 linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7762000)
    libboost_serialization-gcc42-mt-1_34_1.so.1.34.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libboost_serialization-gcc42-mt-1_34_1.so.1.34.1 (0xb76ba000)
    libboost_thread-gcc42-mt-1_34_1.so.1.34.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libboost_thread-gcc42-mt-1_34_1.so.1.34.1 (0xb7695000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb751d000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xb74c8000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb74ab000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb72f5000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xb72d8000)
    libboost_system.so.1.58.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.58.0 (0xb72d2000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xb72c9000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x80027000)
```

Checking the links...

```
# ls -la libboost* | grep "\->"
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      24 jun 14  2016 libboost_regex.so -> libboost_regex.so.1.58.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      32 nov  8 14:53 libboost_serialization-gcc42-mt-1_34_1.so.1.34.1 -> libboost_serialization.so.1.58.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      32 jun 14  2016 libboost_serialization.so -> libboost_serialization.so.1.58.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      26 jun 14  2016 libboost_signals.so -> libboost_signals.so.1.58.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      25 jun 14  2016 libboost_system.so -> libboost_system.so.1.58.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      25 nov  8 14:54 libboost_thread-gcc42-mt-1_34_1.so.1.34.1 -> libboost_thread.so.1.58.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      25 jun 14  2016 libboost_thread.so -> libboost_thread.so.1.58.0
```

Checking other similar questions, if I have understood correctly, the “undefined symbol” would mean that the boost lib (thread) containing recursive_timed_mutex cannot be found, but I do not see what I did wrong with the links. I can admit that I am way out of my depth on this one, but I really need to get it to work. Any help would be kindly appreciated.